# networkx minimum_node_cut and node_connectivity

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am using networkx and here is my network.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_edgelist([['a','b'], ['b','c'], ['c','a']])
nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

[image]

Can you please tell me why `minimum_node_cut` returns `b`, whereas `node_connectivity` returns `2`?

```
nx.minimum_node_cut(G, 'a', 'c')
{'b'}

nx.node_connectivity(G, 'a', 'c')
2
```

I was expecting length of `minimum_node_cut` would equal to `node_connectivity`.

Comment: Here `'a'` and `'c'` are connected directly as well, so removing `'b'` will not remove the connection between `'a'` and `'c'`.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

`networkx.minimum_node_cut` - If source and target nodes are provided, this function returns the set of nodes of minimum cardinality that, if removed, would destroy all paths among source and target in G.

`networkx.node_connectivity` - If source and target nodes are provided, this function returns the local node connectivity: the minimum number of nodes that must be removed to break all paths from source to target in G.

The first returns a set of nodes that when removed will break local connectivity, the second returns the minimum number of nodes needed to be  removed to break local connectivity.

It seems to me that the set returned by `networkx.minimum_node_cut` excludes the source and target nodes as the removal of either would trivially break connectivity between them. `networkx.node_connectivity` rightfully reports that 2 nodes must be removed to break local connectivity.

Comment: Yeah that was my guess too but was not sure why `node_connectivity ` and `minimum_node_cut ` do not use the same method to be consistent.

Comment: I'm sure they do, but what set of vertices should `minimum_node_cut` report? The correct solution is either {a, b} _or_ {b, c} which include either the source or destination.