# NetworkX 2.X minimum_node_cut

Tags: networkx

Going off of the graph in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48197199/864684), I'm getting a different result for `nx.minimum_node_cut` in NetworkX versions `1.11` and `2.3`.

[image: graph]

In `1.11`,

```
>>> nx.minimum_node_cut(G, 'a', 'c')
{'b'}
```

In `2.3`,

```
>>> nx.minimum_node_cut(G, 'a', 'c')
[]
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old output was a [bug](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/1812). The [1.11 version](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.11/_modules/networkx/algorithms/connectivity/cuts.html#minimum_st_node_cut) has the old implementation without the extra handling of exactly this case, which was added:

```py
if G.has_edge(s, t) or G.has_edge(t, s):
        return []
```

This was added by fixing the above mentioned [issue #1812](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/1812) and is already included in the [2.0 version](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.0/_modules/networkx/algorithms/connectivity/cuts.html#minimum_st_node_cut).